# os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)) returns nothing

Tags: python

I have a directory structure like this:

```
--bin/
--lib/
--data/
```

So basically, the executable script is in bin and it calls the files in lib.. but lib has to communicate with the text files in data

Usually this use to work:
TO read a file in usually i use to do this

```
file_path =  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))+ "/../" +"data/"+filename
f = open(file_path,"r")
```

But, in this instance, if i do:

```
  print os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))
  returns nothing?
```

What am i doing wrong..
Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of the exact contents of __ file__

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess with *nothing* you mean an empty string? This could only be the case, if `__file__` was an empty string in the first place. Did you accidentally overwrite `__file__`?

Comment: I am not sure, I quite understand... (sorry.. still learning all this).. there are two files, file1.py over there I am reading a file.. and it works.. and then in file2.py (which is read after file1.py) and i do this same thing.. but it returns empty string

Comment: hey.. thanks.. it works.. my bad.. I was doing this.
filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))+ "/../" +"data/"+filename
So it was returning a null.. as file name and then +"/.." means going cding to null i think :) thanks

Answer (score 3):

One other comment in addition to the others...the point of `os.path.join` is to avoid things like

```
mypath=dir + '/' + subdir + '/'+filename
```

This is done much more cleanly using

```
mypath=os.path.join(dir,subdir,filename) # can have as many arguments as you want!
```

Also, you can avoid explicit '..' and '.' in path names by using `os.pardir` and `os.curdir`. (e.g.)

```
file_path =  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),os.pardir,'data',filename)
```

This should increase the portability of your code (and is a good habit to get into even if you don't plan on running this script anywhere else).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you start your script, for example:

if `/bin/script.py` contains:

```
import os
print os.path.dirname(__file__)   #no reason to use os.path.join()
```

then:

```
$> python /bin/script.py
/bin
$> cd /bin
$> python script.py
                       #nothing
$>
```

It'a a better idea to use the following:

```
file_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

and then do whatever you want with that.