# What does os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir)) mean? python

Tags: python, import, path, operating-system, directory

In several SO's question there is these lines to access the parent directory of the code, e.g. [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)) returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953540/os-path-joinos-path-dirname-file-returns-nothing) and [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)) returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953540/os-path-joinos-path-dirname-file-returns-nothing)

```
import os, sys
parentddir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir))
sys.path.append(parentddir)
```

I understand that `os.path.abspath()` returns absolute path of something and `sys.path.append()` adds the path for the code to access. but what is this cryptic line below, **what does it really mean?**

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir))
```

Is there another way to achieve the same purpose of appending the parent directory of the where the code?

This problem happens because I am calling functions across directories and sometimes they share the same file name, e.g. `script1/utils.py` and `script2/utils.py`. I am calling a function from `script1/test.py` which calls `script2/something.py` contains a function that calls `script2/utils.py` and the following code

```
script1/
        utils.py
        src/
            test.py

script2/
        utils.py
        code/
            something.py
```

**test.py**

```
from script2.code import something
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
import utils

something.foobar()
```

**something.py**

```
import os, sys
parentddir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir))
sys.path.append(parentddir)
import utils

def foobar():
  utils.somefunc()
```

Comment: Just a question, are you saying that you need to do that in order to `import utils`? I don't get the last part right.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

That is a clever way to refer to paths regardless of the script location. The *cryptic* line you're referring is:

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir))
```

There are 3 methods and a 2 constants present:

1. `abspath` returns absolute path of a path
2. `join` join to path strings
3. `dirname` returns the directory of a file
4. `__file__` refers to the `script`'s file name
5. `pardir` returns the representation of a parent directory in the OS (usually `..`)

Thus, the expression returns the *full path name of the executing script* in a *multiplatform-safe* way. No need to *hardwire* any directions, that's why it is so useful.

There might be other approaches to get a parent directory of where a file is located, for example, programs have the concept of current working directory, `os.getcwd()`. So doing `os.getcwd()+'/..'` might work. But this is very dangerous, because working directories can be changed.

Also, if the file is intended to be imported, the working directory will point to the importing file, not the importee, but `__file__` always points to the actual module's file so it is safer.

Hope this helps!

**Edit**: P.S. - Python 3 greatly simplifies this situation by letting us treat paths in an object-oriented manner, so the above line becomes:

```py
from pathlib import Path
Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

Comment: You can't take de path `dirname` of `__file__` because __file__ is only the name of the script.  You need to use `os.getcwd()` to obtain that path.

Comment: In this case, what would be the difference between `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir))` and `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))`? won't they be the same?

Answer (score 21):

`__file__` represents the file the code is executing from

`os.path.dirname(__file__)` gives you the directory the file is in

`os.path.pardir` stands for ".." which means one directory above the current one

`os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir)` joins the directory name and ".."

`os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir))` resolves the above path and gives you an absolute path for the parent directory of the directory your file is in